# Prevent caching of @imported CSS file generated by PHP

Tags: php, css, caching, browser-cache

In my `main.css` file, I have a line

```
@import url("/tags/tags.css");
```

tags.css is a css file that is generated by PHP. It returns styles for the colors defined by the users for the various tag types.

In the PHP file, I start with headers that should prevent caching:

```
 header("Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT");
 header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0")
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Content-Type: text/css");
```

However, the browser still caches the css. If I change a tag color, the new css isn't picked up until I hit shift+refresh.

Because the @import is in a css file, I can't append a `?t=[timestamp]` to the url (as far as I know), and changing it manually with `?v=[version]` doesn't help because it's the users changing the colors independently of the code being updated.

Note: I have also tried putting the anti-caching headers in the apache2 virtual host configuration file, but that didn't seem to help either.

How can I prevent this css file from being cached?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure out any good solution to this?

Comment: I did not unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting to include a timestamp in the url if none is present when intially requested:

```
if (!isset($_GET['t'])) {
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?t=".time());
    die();
}
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference unfortunately